# How to change color in the subtitle dialog of Chromecast android sender SDK?

Tags: android, google-cast, google-cast-sdk, android-cast-api

I would like to change the color of options provided in subtitle selection dialog of cast sender SDK.

I have tried bunch of different things like,

```
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white100</item>
<item name="android:colorForeground">@color/white100</item>
<item name="android:textColor">@color/white100</item>
<item name="textColorAlertDialogListItem">@color/white100</item>
<item name="android:textColorAlertDialogListItem">@color/white100</item>
```

None of them worked...

Any idea what I should I do ?

[image: Chromecast Subtitle Selection View]

Comment: Is this question not a dublicate of this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34240039/android-alertdialog-title-background-color

Comment: @eli not really...this dialog is embedded in cast google cast sender sdk..also i am not finding any class which i can override with custom layout....and i have mentioned above i have tried pretty much everything in changing app theme...but it didn't help

Comment: Hey @Nishant can you please let us know how where you able to get CC/caption option and audio track option? Please share the source code.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this and even posted a bounty for this, but at the end figured out that I had to override

```
cast_tracks_chooser_dialog_layout.xml
```

and

```
cast_tracks_chooser_dialog_row_layout.xml
```

in order to customise them properly